# finish() not finishing the activity: Android

Tags: android, callback, android-activity, activity-finish

I have an Activity in whose onCreate() method i call a Utility function. 
This utility functions requires a callback class instance as a parameter, in which it returns the info that i need. this is:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    
         Utility.functionA(new functionACallBack() {
                /**
                 * 
                 */
                private static final long serialVersionUID = -7896922737679366614L;

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String error) {

                     ((MyActivity) AppClass.getAppContext()).finish();
                }
            });
}
```

Once I have obtained that info, I want to close the activity. so i called finish() from inside the anonymous class that i created for the callback.

But the activity is not getting finished. I thought maybe i need to call finish() from UI thread so i did runOnUiThread(), in inside it also i tried calling finish(). But it just doesn't work.

Could someone please help me with this issue?

UPDATE:

I am storing APP context and then trying to use that but to no avail.

```
public class AppClass extends Application {

    private static Context mContext;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        AppClass.mContext = getApplicationContext();

    }

    public static Context getAppContext(){
        return AppClass.mContext;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried calling `YourActivity.finish()`?

Comment: i tried but Utility.functionA() is a static function and it doesn't let me call non-static from inside it..

Comment: Then try declaring a `static` function within your `Activity` which would call `YourActivity.finish()` and call that function in your `onResponse()` method.

Comment: Yea you need to call finish directly from your activity, right now it is getting called from your Utility function.

Comment: how do i do that...@zgc7009?

Comment: @nKn, how is that supposed to work? if i have a static function, i will run into the same problem as before?

Comment: @Sunny how did you go about solving this?

Answer (score 1):

Simply call something like this:

```
@Override
public void onResponse(String error) {
  ((Activity) context).finish();
}
```

As this is a `static` function, you'll have to be able to access your `Context` in a `static` way. You can save that as a Class variable, but you'll have to be aware about its handling as it might lead to memory leaks.

To avoid them, you can declare a class that `extends Application` and save here your context, so this way you won't ever have a memory leak.

Comment: You can't call `finish()` in a `static` way like that.

Comment: there is nothing called MyActivity.finish()

Comment: You're right, I changed the code as the he has to use `context` to do that.

Comment: but then i can directly call ((Activity) context).finish(); from inside response? will that not work?

Comment: ok i tried that and i took separate class in which i stored the application context. then when i use that here i get a classcast exception

Comment: You should update the code you currently have in your question to see where is the error.

Comment: How do you get the `Context` from that class? It should be something like this: `AppClass appclass = ((AppClass) getApplicationContext());` `final Context myContext = appclass.getContext();`

Comment: but won't it work since i am storing it in the AppClass as a static variable and then calling via the static method? what is wrong in that?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm doing by these two lines. The first one gets the `static` object of it within the application (this way you will get the actual value of the `Context` anywhere you declare it), and the second one returns the `Context`, which is what you need at that point.

Comment: pardon my asking, but if my method is static (public static Context getCESDemoAppContext(){
  return CESDemoApplication.mContext;
 }) then why do i need the first line that u mentioned (AppClass appclass = ((AppClass) getApplicationContext());) as i have already stored the context in that class?

Comment: Because with that line you're not declaring a new instance of `AppClass`, you're telling that you want to cast the `ApplicationContext` (which is an `Application` class) to your `AppClass` (which is an extension of `Application`). This way basically you're saying you want to get the current **instance** of the `AppClass`, which contains your `Context`. This way you can then get the context via `getContext()` method.

Comment: @nKn, i am still a little confused about this

Comment: Take a look at this: http://www.devahead.com/blog/2011/06/extending-the-android-application-class-and-dealing-with-singleton/

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code:

```
((Activity) ActivityClass.this).finish();
```

Remember, use the Activity class, not the Application one.

Comment: You are calling this from within the activity class or the application one?

Comment: i am calling this from inside onResponse function as mentioned in initial quesdtion

Comment: The cast here is pretty redundant